# Panda numerical manipulations on a dataframe (i.e. max())

Tags: python, pandas

So I know this looks trivial at face value, but what I'm trying to do is actually different.

I have a dataframe:

```
x
1
3
4
```

and I want to do a manipulation on it, such as:

```
df['x']=df['x']+1
```

But I also have a maximum value on this, which is effectively `min(4,val)`.

This would achieve output:

```
x
2
4
4
```

So, in invalidate syntax, I guess what I'm trying to do is: `df['x']=np.min(df['x']+1,4)` but this doesn't work.

Aside from doing:

```
df['x']=df['x']+1
df[df['x']>4]['x']=4
```

does anyone have a more elegant solution?

Thanks

Comment: Why not `df[df['x']<4]['x'] += 1`?

Comment: So interestingly I tried a variant on this - `df['x']=df['x']+1` and then `df[df['x']>4]['x']=4` and that didn't work for some reason. Dont understand why not tbh. I've done similiar operations before with no joy

Comment: @Henry That's called chained indexing and it may produce strange results. Instead of `df[df['x']>4]['x']=4`, you can use `df.loc[df['x']>4, 'x']=4`.

Comment: @Henry Well the answers below looks more readable anyways, and I'm sure they're pretty efficient too.

Comment: Thanks to all for helping. I have indeed implemented one of the answers below, but that was one of my attempts before asking Stack :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['x'] = np.where(df['x'] > 3, 4, df['x'] + 1)
#same as
#df['x'] = np.where(df['x'] > 4 - 1, 4, df['x'] + 1)
print (df)
   x
0  2
1  4
2  4
```

Or [`clip_upper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip_upper.html):

```
df['x'] = (df['x'] + 1).clip_upper(4)
print (df)
   x
0  2
1  4
2  4
```

Maybe nicer with [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html):

```
df['x'] = df['x'].add(1).clip_upper(4)
print (df)
   x
0  2
1  4
2  4
```

EDIT:

Need [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for new values by condition:

```
df['x']=df['x'] + 1
df.loc[df['x'] > 4, 'x'] = 4
print (df)
   x
0  2
1  4
2  4
```

Comment: @Henry - Glad can help!

Answer (score 3):

You can use clip:

```
(df['x'] + 1).clip(upper=4)

0    2
1    4
2    4
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

The following would also work:

```
np.minimum(df['x'] + 1, 4)

0    2
1    4
2    4
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

What you did didn't work because np.min expects an array. np.minimum, however, compares two values (or arrays) so it can broadcast.